# Flex 3 color picker no color value

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I need "no color" value in flex 3/4 color picker component. Here are some options I've investigated:

1) External componet. Searched a lot but didn't managed to find a suitable one. There is a great color picker that meets my needs completely, but it is in action script 2 format. I need as3.

2) Enhance the existing built-in color picker component.

So here I need your help. Do you have any ideas how the built-in color picker component can be enhanced in order to support "no color" value?

Comment: 'no color' as in `No color selected`?

Comment: if it's a single component, porting from AS2 to AS3 won't be a big deal.

Comment: Yes "No color selected". I've tried to port the component from as2 to as3 and it seemed to me a big deal as I am not expert in actionscript and have never dealt with as2. May be I should hire a freelancer to do this job, how much could it be cost?

Answer (score 0):

We had this same problem.  We ended up just putting a "clear button" to the right of the color picker.  Not ideal.

Comment: We use radio buttons: 
"Background: ( ) transparent (x) color: [picker]" 
If "transparent" is checked, picker is invalidated, if color is checked, the color in the picker is used. Transparent can be changed to "nothing" or something better.